# Convert and modify list in python

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have a list like so obtained after some mathematic operations:

```
[[899, 6237], [898, 6237], [897, 6237],
 [896, 6237], [895, 6237], [899, 6238],
 [898, 6238], [897, 6238], [896, 6238],
 [895, 6238], [899, 6239], [898, 6239],
 [897, 6239], [896, 6239], [895, 6239],
 [899, 6240], [898, 6240], [897, 6240],
 [896, 6240], [895, 6240]]
```

I would like the components of each sublist become string of 4 characters size. This is a example of what I want with the first element of the main list:

```
['0899','6237']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> lst = [
...     [899, 6237], [898, 6237], [897, 6237], [896, 6237], [895, 6237],
...     [899, 6238], [898, 6238], [897, 6238], [896, 6238], [895, 6238],
...     [899, 6239], [898, 6239], [897, 6239], [896, 6239], [895, 6239],
...     [899, 6240], [898, 6240], [897, 6240], [896, 6240], [895, 6240],
... ]
>>> [[format(a, '04'), format(b, '04')] for a, b in lst]
[['0899', '6237'], ['0898', '6237'], ['0897', '6237'], ['0896', '6237'],
 ['0895', '6237'], ['0899', '6238'], ['0898', '6238'], ['0897', '6238'],
 ['0896', '6238'], ['0895', '6238'], ['0899', '6239'], ['0898', '6239'],
 ['0897', '6239'], ['0896', '6239'], ['0895', '6239'], ['0899', '6240'],
 ['0898', '6240'], ['0897', '6240'], ['0896', '6240'], ['0895', '6240']]
```

You can also use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> '{:04}'.format(899)
'0899'
```

or [`%`-operator (`printf`-style formatting)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
>>> '%04d' % 899
'0899'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zfill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_name = [[str(i).zfill(4) for i in element] for element in your_list]
```

Demo:

```
>>>str(890).zfill(4)
'0890'
>>>str(890).zfill(5)
'00890'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `list comprehension`

```
new_list = [['0' + str(i[0]), str(i[1])]  for i in original_list]
```

`new_list` output:

```
[['0899', '6237'], ['0898', '6237'], ['0897', '6237'], ['0896', '6237'], ['0895', '6237'], ['0899', '6238'], ['0898', '6238'], ['0897', '6238'], ['0896', '6238'], ['0895', '6238'], ['0899', '6239'], ['0898', '6239'], ['0897', '6239'], ['0896', '6239'], ['0895', '6239'], ['0899', '6240'], ['0898', '6240'], ['0897', '6240'], ['0896', '6240'], ['0895', '6240']]
```

Comment: It is not clear if there are any `int > 999`, but if there are, formatting (as in the other answers) will achieve better results.

Comment: @N.Wouda My answer works for the `list` the OP posted, assuming there are no `int > 999` in the list. If there were any, he should have mentioned that in his question.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use format(), although the zfill is also pretty sweet.
Here is a much uglier solution that no one should ever use:

```
list = [
 [899, 6237], [898, 6237], [897, 6237], [896, 6237], [895, 6237], [899, 6238],
 [898, 6238], [897, 6238], [896, 6238], [895, 6238], [899, 6239], [898, 6239],
 [897, 6239], [896, 6239], [895, 6239], [899, 6240], [898, 6240], [897, 6240],
 [896, 6240], [895, 6240]
]

def yolo(pair):
    pair = map(str,pair)
    return ['0'*(4-len(pair[0])) + pair[0], pair[1]]

list = map(yolo,list)
```